# How should a floating element be aligned vertically if it's under other floating elements?

Tags: html, css, css-float

There is a container that accommodates four left-floating `div`s, `width` of each of them is set to `50%` (two in a row). Besides, I added a `top-margin` value for every `div` but the first (by means of this owl-like selector `* + *`).

Inasmuch as the first `div` has less text inside itself than the second, it is possible their heights result in different values (the first would smaller). In this case, to my expectations, the third `div` will find its place right beneath the first one, with only its `top-margin` preventing it to touch the first. Instead, I found this picture:

[image]

Apparently, the third `div` comes up to the second one' vertical level. Could anybody elaborate on this rule? Why is not the third `div` lifted up as much high as it is possible to it (to the first `div`)?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1uovx83m/1/)

Comment: To obtaine your layout it's not a good solution using float.... better use flexbox or grid

Comment: @Sfili_81 Yes, I'm aware of this option, but for now I'm just trying to grasp floating.

Comment: why you add margin top this way `body * + * `?

Comment: @Sfili_81 It's a convenient way to achieve a vertical gap between vertically aligned elements (and we do not want it would be applyed to the first one, as to the `body` itself)

Comment: @Sfili_81 okay, in this case the `top-margin` should *be applied* to the first `div` (I made this sample with a view to turn these divs into one-div-in-a-row later). Nevertheless, my question still remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic of `float:left` layout is - place to the right of preceding left floats if there's space or underneath them if there isn't. Not - fill in the first space big enough for the box.

Exactly why is not obvious. I suspect it was just both sufficient for the target use cases and simple enough to implement at the time it was specified.

Comment: I at first recognized your answer in such a way that a floating element can't be placed higher than the bottoms of preceding ones, so it's the very reason why the third `div` has that place in my example. However, if the first `div` contains more content than the second, the third may [find its position higher](https://jsfiddle.net/2m7Ljpd0/) than the bottom line of the *first*. To get things straight: *if there is no place from the right of preceding floats, fill in the first place underneath them, but don't lift it up higher than the **immediate** predecessor's bottom line*.

Comment: Could you say have I finally got it right?

Comment: @Mergasov - Kind of, but not just the _immediate_ predecessor. There might be several predecessors that it has to move below before there's space to fit it. This fitting process requires that its margin top will never be higher than the margin bottom of any left floated element to the right of it. If you want to understand it exactly, [a float's precise rules](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/#float-rules) are given in the CSS 2 spec.